# Packer: Build 'openstack' errored: Timeout waiting for WinRM

Tags: timeout, openstack, packer, winrm

I am trying to create a windows image in Openstack cloud using Packer. The VM is getting created successfully but the packer build is getting hanged for quite long period(30 mins) and finally throws "`ui error: Build 'openstack' errored: Timeout waiting for WinRM`". Please find the logs below and help me in getting this issue resolved. I have tried opening 5985 WinRM port as well but still it didn't worked.

```
[INFO] Attempting WinRM connection...

[DEBUG] connecting to remote shell using WinRM

[ERROR] connection error: unknown error Post http://{IP}:5985/wsman: dial tcp {IP}:5985: connection timed out

[ERROR] WinRM connection err: unknown error Post http://{IP}:5985/wsman: dial tcp {IP}:5985: connection timed out

==> openstack: Timeout waiting for WinRM.

ui error: Build 'openstack' errored: Timeout waiting for WinRM.
```

Comment: Attach your template, scripts, and tell which version of Windows you are using.

Comment: Hi Rickard, 
Please find the Packer build file below and I already have a Windows-2012-R2 image exists in the Openstack cloud. Now I am trying to create a golden image from this base image by patching it.

Comment: {
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "openstack",
      "identity_endpoint": "API_Endpoint_URL",
      "communicator": "winrm",
      "winrm_username": "",
      "winrm_password": "",
      "insecure": "true",
      "image_name": "Packer_Windows_Image",
      "source_image": "IMAGE_ID",
      "flavor": "4",
      "tenant_id": "TENANT_ID",
      "networks": "NETWORK_ID"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "test.txt",
      "destination": "C:\"
    }
]
}

Comment: Hi Rickard,
The above issue is resolved now as it is because the firewall issue as both the instances are running in difference network zones. Now I have a question here, the golden image which gets created after patching from the base image of size 9 GB is getting uploaded as "SNAPSHOT" to Openstack cloud and the image is also around 40 GB in size. Is there a way where the image can be uploaded as "Image" with the same size(around 9GB) as the base image?

Comment: And the Packer version which I am using is 1.2.0 and also tried with 0.8 and 0.9, but it is not working. I have added the label "image_type": "image" to the Packer build file, but it is throwing an error - * unknown configuration key: "image_type" for all the above 3 versions

Comment: I think you are looking for the Glance support requested in https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/2678.